# How to create a loop that only changes the year in a url?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to loop two parts of my code. The first part has a clear structure - it only changes the year in the url:

```
library(rvest)

# first step

# for 2020

x = html_attr(html_nodes(read_html("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2020/html/index_include.en.html"), ".doc-title a"), name = "href")

# for 2019 

x = html_attr(html_nodes(read_html("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2019/html/index_include.en.html"), ".doc-title a"), name = "href")


# for 2018

x = html_attr(html_nodes(read_html("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2018/html/index_include.en.html"), ".doc-title a"), name = "href")

# and so on
```

I would like to have a loop that gives me all the "links" for years from 2000 to 2020. If we take only the results for 2020, I get this:

```
[1] "/press/pressconf/2020/html/ecb.is200716~3865f74bf8.en.html"
[2] "/press/pressconf/2020/html/ecb.is200604~b479b8cfff.en.html"
[3] "/press/pressconf/2020/html/ecb.is200430~ab3058e07f.en.html"
[4] "/press/pressconf/2020/html/ecb.is200312~f857a21b6c.en.html"
[5] "/press/pressconf/2020/html/ecb.is200123~0bc778277b.en.html"
```

This brings me to the second question: I would like to paste the *same* first part of the url (first element in the function below) with all the element I obtained from loop one:

```
y = paste0("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2020/html/", "/press/pressconf/2020/html/ecb.is200716~3865f74bf8.en.html")

y1 = paste0("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2020/html/", "/press/pressconf/2020/html/ecb.is200604~b479b8cfff.en.html")

y2 = paste0("https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2020/html/", "/press/pressconf/2020/html/ecb.is200430~ab3058e07f.en.html")

# etc....
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: How about `paste0("https://www.ecb.europa.eu", "/press/pressconf/", 2000:2020, "/html/ecb.is200123~0bc778277b.en.html")`?

Comment: @Bas it is a good point, I am trying to apply the function for each element in that vector

Comment: You can use a `for` loop for that, or look into `lapply`. For example: `lapply(paste0("https://www.ecb.europa.eu", "/press/pressconf/", 2000:2020, "/html/index_include.en.html"), function(x) html_attr(html_nodes(read_html(x), ".doc-title a"), name = "href"))`.

Comment: I think  the final thing you're interested in is `paste0("https://www.ecb.europa.eu", unlist(lapply(paste0("https://www.ecb.europa.eu", "/press/pressconf/", 2000:2020, "/html/index_include.en.html"), function(x) html_attr(html_nodes(read_html(x), ".doc-title a"), name = "href"))))`, but at this point it is way better to split everything up into functions and separate steps.

Comment: Just a short contribution to the @Bas suggestion. It is always better to add a delay inside the codes in any scraping process. You may want to add `Sys.sleep()` as weel.

Comment: @Bas this looks very very good, you should post it as an answer I can give you points at least. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a full step-by-step solution below. As per @maydin's comment I added a `Sys.sleep()` to make sure we don't fire too many request too quickly.

```
library(rvest)

base_url <- "https://www.ecb.europa.eu"
year_urls <- paste0(base_url, "/press/pressconf/", 2000:2020, "/html/index_include.en.html")

scrape_page <- function(url) {
  Sys.sleep(runif(1))
  
  html_attr(html_nodes(read_html(url), ".doc-title a"), name = "href")
}

all_pages <- lapply(year_urls, scrape_page)

all_pages <- paste0(base_url, unlist(all_pages))
```

Which gives

```
> all_pages
  [1] "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/is001214.en.html"               
  [2] "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/is001102.en.html"               
  [3] "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/is001019.en.html"               
  [4] "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/is001005.en.html"               
  [5] "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/is000914.en.html"               
  [6] "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/is000706.en.html"               
  [7] "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2000/html/is000608.en.html"
   ...
```